# How can I get a history of directories I visited in the commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line, history

I know you can get the command history in some consoles, but is history for the visited directories stored in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@picardo, the command history is not maintained across  sessions, only is stored in memory, The most similar to what you ask, is performed by a very-old tool called [DOSKey](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true).

DOSKey was part of the old DOS command shell (and still works even in Windows 7!). It provided command-line editing, history functions for recalling commands.

For more info check these links:

- [DOSKey](http://commandwindows.com/doskey.htm)
- [Configuring the Command Prompt Window](http://commandwindows.com/configure.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.